# Visual Studio 2012 TFS Checked out by someone else or in another place

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops, tfvc

> TFS 2012 Checked out by someone else or in another place.

Is there a way to see by who this change is checkout?
I know, because the source code has not been published to the server yet, there's no way to fetch the changes made by that person. Aldo is there no way to get to know who is working on it?

Yes, i can ask arround in the team who is, but we have several teams in different offices.
So its not that obvious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple ways to see who has a file checked out. The mentioned TFS Power tools are one way. Another is to use the commandline tools:

> `tf status $/TeamProject/Path/To/File.ext`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f) (Visual Studio Add-in) and do a search "by Status"

That will show you which items are checked-out, by who and in which workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around to get this information, though this procedure may not always be possible. ***The check-out log shows the list of users who have the file/files checked out.***

Right-click on a file/folder and choose `Check Out for Edit`. In the Output window (if not visible, go to View > Output), you should see something like this:

```
$/Dev/SharePoint/Finance.Sandbox/Resources/GlobalResources.resx:
   opened for edit in TGTRAPP22155;Nigel.Hewitt
   opened for edit in SRCGAPP21921;Bob.Carlo
   opened for edit in ARSYAPP22182;RDP-ADMN-Jane.Pierre
```

This should tell you the name of the user and the machine on which the file has been checked out.

(To undo your own check out operation that you just did to get the above information, right-click on the same file/folder and choose `Undo Pending Changes`. If prompted if you want to *"Undo check-out and discard changes?"*, choose *"No to All"* to preserve your existing changes and only roll-back check-out on files that don't have changes.)